# Date Picker Android Show Random Date

Tags: java, android

Setting up Date picker using **Datapicker.update(year,month,day);** gives me random date even if the date is correct so any help please I use the same Activity for Add or Edit a Task

here is my Code

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);
    databaseConnector = new DatabaseConnector(this);
    title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TitleET);
    subject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.SubjectET);
    category = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.CategorySpinner);
    datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Category, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    category.setAdapter(adapter);
     extra = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extra !=null)
    {
        String [] spli = extra.getString("Date").split("-");
        row_id = extra.getLong("row_id");
        title.setText(extra.getString("Title"));
        subject.setText(extra.getString("Subject"));
        if(extra.getString("Category").equals("Exam"))
        {
            category.setSelection(0);
        }
        else
        {
            category.setSelection(1);
        }
        datePicker.updateDate(Integer.parseInt(spli[2]),Integer.parseInt(spli[1]),Integer.parseInt(spli[0]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DatePicker.updateDate()`'s month argument starts from zero. From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#updateDate%28int,%20int,%20int%29):

> *month*    The month which is **starting from zero**.

So, as the second argument, use `Integer.parseInt(spli[1]) - 1`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the correct approach but i edited this line of code and it works fine

```
datePicker.updateDate(Integer.parseInt(spli[2]),Integer.parseInt(spli[1]),Integer.parseInt(spli[0]));
    }
```

changed to

```
 datePicker.updateDate(Integer.parseInt(spli[2]),Integer.parseInt(spli[1])-1,Integer.parseInt(spli[0]));
```

and i dont know the logic behind it but it works